# Drools optaplanner rule not working

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine, rule, optaplanner

I am building a simple application to manage teams. My problem is that I can not get the constraints/rules right to cover my rules. My result is unique player combination in ONE round but not for ALL rounds.

How can I get my rules right so I get unique player combo's for ALL rounds and how do I loop over rounds in the rules instead of doing a ruleset for each round which are basically the same except ($round.getId()+1, $round.getId+2 etc)

The rules: uniqueMatchingX should be repeated for all rounds instead of coding them out..

I have the following domain objects:

Player
   ranking
Match (@PlanningEntity)
   id
   2x a player (@PlanningVariable)
   Round
Round
   id
Tournament (@PlanningSolution)
   list of matches
   list of players
   list of rounds

In the solution I populate the facts (6 players with variable rankings, 2 round, and 6 matches 3 for each round)
In the matched I do NOT populate the players, as this will be done by optaplanner.

I have defined the following rules:
  Hard constraints
      you can not play against yourself
      you can not play against the same opponent (in any round)
  soft constraints
      You must play against a players close to your ranking

I have implemented these rules as follows:

```
// ############################################################################
// Hard constraints
// ############################################################################

rule "uniqueMatching1"
    when
       $m : Match($player1 : player1, $player2 : player2, $round1 : round)
       Match(player1 == $player1, eval(round.getId() == $round1.getId()))
       or Match(player1 == $player2, eval(round.getId() == $round1.getId()))
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext,  -1);
end

rule "uniqueMatching2"
    when
       $m : Match($player1 : player1, $player2 : player2, $round1 : round)
       Match(player2 == $player1, eval(round.getId() == $round1.getId()))
       or Match(player2 == $player2, eval(round.getId() == $round1.getId()))
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext,  -1);
end

rule "uniqueMatching1Round2"
    when
       $m : Match($player1 : player1, $player2 : player2, $round1 : round)
       Match(player1 == $player1, eval(round.getId() == $round1.getId()+1))
       or Match(player1 == $player2, eval(round.getId() == $round1.getId()+1))
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext,  -1);
end

rule "uniqueMatching2Round2"
    when
       $m : Match($player1 : player1, $player2 : player2, $round1 : round)
       Match(player2 == $player1, eval(round.getId() == $round1.getId()+1))
       or Match(player2 == $player2, eval(round.getId() == $round1.getId()+1))
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext,  -1);
end

rule "uniquePlayers"
    when
       Match(player1 == player2)
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext,  -1);
end

// ############################################################################
// Soft constraints
// ############################################################################

rule "minimumPointDifference"
    when
       $m : Match($player1 : player1, $player2 : player2, $round1 : round)
       Match(player1!=null, player2!=null,$player1!=null, $player2!=null)
    then
       scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext,  $player1.scoreGap($player2));
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you are trying to plan a Swiss-system tournament. However, your rules are rather faulty except for `uniquePlayers`.

Conditions of the form

```
when
   $m : Match($player1 : player1, $player2 : player2, $round1 : round)
   Match(player2 == $player1, eval(round.getId() == $round1.getId()))
   or Match(player2 == $player2, eval(round.getId() == $round1.getId()))
```

are not useful at all. For 6 players and three rounds, this rule will fire *more than one thousand times*. Mostly is due to the use of `or` and missing parentheses. Also, you shouldn't need to use eval(). Perhaps `Round.equals(Object o)` should be based on the comparison of the round id alone, or use the round id (int) as an attribute of Match, not a reference to some Round object.

Here is a couple of rules you could use as a starting point. (I'm disregarding the additional quirk of chess tournaments, where players must have a fair share of white vs. black.)

```
rule "no rematch" // If we have A:B, we don't consider B:A at all.
when
    $m : Match($player1 : player1, $player2 : player2)
    $m1: Match(player1 == $player2, player2 == $player1)
then
   // hard constraint on $m1
end
```

I'm also disregarding the dynamic development, i.e., the changes on Match facts due to the actional selections in the first round, which need to be known to plan the second round.

```
rule "only one match" 
// If we have A:B in round n, it won't happen again
// Need an indiaction what has actually been played in rounds 1..n.
when
    $m : Match($player1 : player1, $player2 : player2, $round : round)
    $m1: Match(player1 == $player1, player2 == $player2, round > $round)
then
    // hard constraint on $m1
end
```

Rule `uniquePlayers` is OK, but I don't think that `minimumPointDifference` is doing anything helpful as it will fire many, many times, too.

Comment: Hi,
Sorry for the late response. I have been very busy with other parts of my application.
Well you found out that I am a complete noob using this.
I have added your suggestions to my code, and The following happens;

Comment: Hi,
Sorry for the late response. I have been very busy with other parts of my application and some RL stuff.
Well you found out that I am a complete noob using this.
I have added your suggestions to my code, and the following happens;

The first solution is always for every match the first 2 persons from the list and the final solution (after the time is up) is NULL - NULL for players. aka null objects

Iam also seeing an issue; KieContext found but expected RuleContext.
I can not find a resource online that helps me with this problem.

Comment: If you have KieContext vs. RuleContext this looks like a mixup of Drools 5.x and Drools 6.x. To be avoided for sure.

Comment: That I can do :) thanx. As you saw I am a bit frustrated atm.
I have put my mvn project on github, since I am unable to solve the problems 
https://github.com/kwantm/swizztournament
With my crappy rules I got atleast 1 good result, but then all null values in the final result
My goal is; 1. plan players per round. 2. no player must play against the same opponent. 3. minimum score difference (soft) 
But even this simple idea, I am unable to implement.
Maybe someone can assist me using my code on github